# How to represent a $C_{c}^{1}$ function as a integral of its differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Given an open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ why should a $u \in C_{c}^{+\infty}(\Omega)$ satisfy this equality
$$ u(x)=\frac{1}{d\cdot \omega_{d}}\cdot\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{d}D_{i}u(y)\cdot\frac{(x_i-y_i)}{|x-y|^d} dy?$$
I'm studying on the Jurgen Jost's book of PDE, this identity is used to prove the Sobolev embedding theorem in the case where the summability exponent its bigger than $d$.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating the right-hand side?

Comment: Integrate by parts on the RHS (or Green's identity).  Recall $\lvert x\rvert^{2-d}$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^d-\{0\}$.

Comment: On the book I have not seen any hypotheses about the regularity of the boundary so I did not think of using Green’s identity.

Comment: @PeterMorfe I was not aware I could differentiate this expression under integral sign. I do not think I would be capable of recognizing $Du(x)$ from the integral expression I get, and even if I do I would have proved that the two members of my equality differ for an additive constant. I would still have to prove that the constant is zero.

Comment: @PeterMorfe the j-th derivative of the first expression should be this $$ \frac{1}{d \cdot \omega_d} \cdot \int_{\Omega} \sum_{l=1}^{d} (\frac{\delta_{l,j} }{|x-y|^d}-\frac{d\cdot (x_l-y_l)\cdot (x_j-y_j)}{|x-y|^{d+2}})\cdot D_lu$$.

Comment: @MatteoAldovardi regularity of boundary is irrelevant here since you can extend by 0 to $\mathbb{R}^d$..

Comment: Thanks, maybe I get now. The term $u(x)$ comes out from the boundary term of the Green's identity. I have to apply Green's identity on $\mathbb{R}^{d}\setminus B(x,\epsilon)$ and then I have to send $\epsilon$ to $0$.